# Turning a list into a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, list

I have created the following list of vectors of different lengths:

```
 n.seq <- c(100,200,103,104,105)

    set.seed(0)

    vector_of_values <- list()
    for (n in n.seq) {
    vector_of_values <- rnorm(n)
    }
```

I would like to then turn this list into a data frame to use for ggplot (creating histograms)

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Can you please revise to provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 1):

Your initial question did not have a reproducible example so it is difficult to diagnose what is going awry for your implementation but the code your provided *does* does work if you have a list of vectors with the same number of elements in each vector. See below:

```
vector_of_values <- list(n.seq_100 = 1:100, n.seq_200 = 1:100, n.seq_103 = 1:100, n.seq_104 = 1:100, n.seq_105 = 1:100)
df <- data.frame(do.call(cbind, vector_of_values))
```

My best guess is that in your example, n.seq_100, n.seq_200, n.seq_103 etc. are not equivalent lengths and thus cannot be concatenated into a dataframe. It seems perhaps that is the case if your 100, 200, and 103 denote the length of the sequence. In order for cbind to work on these vectors, ensure the vectors that you would like to concatenate are of equivalent length.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to fix in your code.

You are overwriting `vector_of_values` on each pass of your `for`-loop, so while it starts as a `list`, it is immediately replaced with a vector of random numbers, and then replaced again (repeatedly). One option is to append to it, using

```r
n.seq <- c(100,200,103,104,105)
set.seed(0)
vector_of_values <- list()
for (n in n.seq) {
  vector_of_values <- c(vector_of_values, list(rnorm(n)))
}
str(vector_of_values)
# List of 5
#  $ : num [1:100] 1.263 -0.326 1.33 1.272 0.415 ...
#  $ : num [1:200] 0.7819 -0.7768 -0.616 0.0466 -1.1304 ...
#  $ : num [1:103] -0.124 1.467 0.674 1.956 -0.269 ...
#  $ : num [1:104] 0.46 1.617 -1.856 -0.287 1.75 ...
#  $ : num [1:105] 2.56 1.257 -0.535 -0.625 0.914 ...
```

The list now is length-5 (one for each of `n.seq`), where each vector within it has some number of random numbers. Since a `data.frame` requires each column to be the same length, we cannot create a 5-column frame. Especially sine you want to pass this to `ggplot(.)` which prefers its data in a *long* format, and I'm inferring that you want to preserve *which group* the number is in, I suggest

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  id    = rep(seq_along(n.seq), times = lengths(vector_of_values)),
  n.seq = rep(n.seq, times = lengths(vector_of_values)),
  value = unlist(vector_of_values)
)
head(dat)
#   id n.seq      value
# 1  1   100  1.2629543
# 2  1   100 -0.3262334
# 3  1   100  1.3297993
# 4  1   100  1.2724293
# 5  1   100  0.4146414
# 6  1   100 -1.5399500
tail(dat)
#     id n.seq      value
# 607  5   105  0.6315868
# 608  5   105 -0.5804664
# 609  5   105  1.5841921
# 610  5   105 -1.7639929
# 611  5   105 -1.8806220
# 612  5   105 -1.2917190
```

Technically, since we know how long each group is, we did not need a `list`, though when repeating an expression in a `for`-loop, that is often the preferred way to go.

Alternatively, here are some slightly shorter ways to create this same data.

## base R

```r
set.seed(0)
dat <- lapply(n.seq, function(n) data.frame(value = rnorm(n))) |>
  do.call(rbind, args = _) |>
  transform(
    id    = rep(seq_along(n.seq), times = n.seq),
    n.seq = rep(n.seq, times = n.seq)
  )
```

## dplyr

Really, the only thing I'm using here from `dplyr` is `bind_rows`, though it's not far-fetched to believe that if you're using `ggplot2`, you might benefit from using `dplyr` in other places as well.

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(0)
dat <- lapply(n.seq, function(n) data.frame(value = rnorm(n))) |>
  bind_rows(.id = "id")
```

This discards the `n.seq` embedded within the frame from above, thinking you may not need it. (It's easy to add, either using `mutate(seq = n.seq[id])` or some other trick.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `setNames` to add names to n.seq and then `Map` to iterate over that generating a named list of vectors, `vector_of_values`.  If using sequence numbers to identify the components of `vector_of_values` is desired (instead of their lengths) then replace the first pipeline with `vector_of_values <- setNames(n.seq, seq_along(n.seq)) |> Map(f = rnorm)` .

Now use `stack` to turn that into a long data.frame `DF` with columns `values` and `ind`.

Finally run ggplot2.

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(0)
vector_of_values <- n.seq |>
  setNames(nm = _) |>
  Map(f = rnorm)

DF <- stack(vector_of_values)

ggplot(DF, aes(values)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  facet_wrap(~ ind)
```

[image: screenshot]