# Turning a list of participants with missing values into a data frame

Tags: dataframe, list, stata

I have a data set in Stata with 1,834 participants. Each participant should have a value for age, gender, ses, employment, exercise, pm25, phq9, borough, and smoker. Age, ses, exercise, pm25, and phq9 are numeric variables while the rest are string variables. I have written the following code to list the participants with missing values (there are no missing values for borough, age, and smoker so I have excluded those):

```
list if gender == "NA" | ses == "NA" | employment == "NA" | exercise == "NA" | pm25 == "NA" | phq9 == "NA"
```

How do I turn this list of participants with missing values into its own data frame labeled "excluded sample"?

I have tried the following codes but it only gives me "1" for all of the participants, which I know is incorrect as there are many participants with no missing values:

```
egen missing_datas = max(gender == "NA" | ses == "NA" | employment == "NA" | exercise == "NA" | pm25 == "NA" | phq9 == "NA")

keep if excluded_sample == 1

egen any_missing = any(gender == "NA" | ses == "NA" | employment == "NA" | exercise == "NA" | pm25 == "NA" | phq9 == "NA")

keep if excluded_sample == 1
```

Note: missing data is listed as "NA".

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
egen missing_datas = max(gender == "NA" | ses == "NA" | employment == "NA" | exercise == "NA" | pm25 == "NA" | phq9 == "NA")
```

should be using `rowmax()`, except that that function requires a varlist.

It can be simplified and corrected to

```
gen ismissing = inlist("NA", gender, ses, employment, exercise, pm25, phq9)
```

With that code the result should be 1 if any variable mentioned is `"NA"` and 0 otherwise. The command is only legal if all the variables on the right-hand side are string.

It is better practice in Stata to replace `"NA"` with empty strings and then `egen, rowmiss()` would allow a direct solution.

However, there are other problems with your question.

1. You don't give a reproducible data example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for the standard here. The need for such was flagged in your previous thread: [Turning a list into a data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77507762/turning-a-list-into-a-data-frame-in-r)
2. You state that "`ses`, `exercise`, `pm25`, and `phq9` are numeric variables" but your code implies otherwise.
3. You don't explain how the variable `excluded_sample` is calculated.
4. 

```
egen any_missing = any(gender == "NA" | ses == "NA" | employment == "NA" | exercise == "NA" | pm25 == "NA" | phq9 == "NA")
```

is illegal code unless you're using a community-contributed `egen` function you don't explain.

Note. Strictly in Stata an observation is, in other terms, an entire record, row or case in the dataset. It's not another name for value.